# Connect separate lists in HTML for assistive technology

Tags: html, accessibility, wai-aria, screen-readers

In my HTML, I have a description list which I had to split up for presentational purposes.

Let's assume the following HTML:

```
<div class="styling-1">
  <dl id="list-1">
    <dt>Item 1</dt>
    <dd>Description 1</dd>

    <dt>Item 2</dt>
    <dd>Description 2</dd>
  </dl>
</div>
<div class="styling-2">
  <dl id="list-2">
    <dt>Item 3</dt>
    <dd>Description 3</dd>

    <dt>Item 4</dt>
    <dd>Description 4</dd>
  </dl>
</div>
```

> **EDIT:** Side note for clarification: I cannot use a CSS grid, column layout, ... to take one semantic list and adjust the distribution of its items. The lists are required to be kept separate *in HTML*.

Now macOS' VoiceOver naturally announces this as two description lists. This is not a deal breaker, but since they are — semantically — a single list, it would be better to have them announced as one.

Hence my question: Does WAI-ARIA (or any other declarative tool) offer a way to tell assistive technology that `list-2` is a continuation of `list-1`?

Comment: When you say you split the lists up for presentation purposes, I first wonder would you be fine with an answer that keeps this as one list, but uses CSS to present it differently? For example, one list can appear as two columns with CSS alone.

Comment: No. The styling requires the wrapping elements around the lists, I can neither use CSS columns nor a grid layout. I considered clarifying that in my question, I'll edit the question to make that clear. (It's also why I haven't tagged this with "css".) Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now macOS' VoiceOver naturally announces this as two description lists. This is not a deal breaker, but since they are — semantically — a single list, it would be better to have them announced as one.

You're approaching the problem the wrong way round IMHO. The display of your document shouldn't dictate its semantic.

If both lists should be in one single list then do that and find a way to "separate" them on the screen.

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dl), it's ok to wrap `<dt>, <dd>` pairs in `<div>`:

> WHATWG HTML allows wrapping each name-value group in a  element in a  element. This can be useful when using microdata, or when global attributes apply to a whole group, or for styling purposes.

```html
<dl>
  <div>
    <dt>Name</dt>
    <dd>Godzilla</dd>
  </div>
  <div>
    <dt>Born</dt>
    <dd>1952</dd>
  </div>
  <div>
    <dt>Birthplace</dt>
    <dd>Japan</dd>
  </div>
  <div>
    <dt>Color</dt>
    <dd>Green</dd>
  </div>
</dl>
```

So you should be able to "break" this single list into two:

```html
<dl>
  <div>
    <dt>Name</dt>
    <dd>Godzilla</dd>
  </div>
  <div>
    <dt>Born</dt>
    <dd>1952</dd>
  </div>
  <div class="new-column">
    <dt>Birthplace</dt>
    <dd>Japan</dd>
  </div>
  <div>
    <dt>Color</dt>
    <dd>Green</dd>
  </div>
</dl>
```

Comment: I'm aware that style shouldn't force semantics, but style is not always in developers' hands. I hoped that a more generic approach is available (possibly even including regular `<ul>`/`<ol>` lists), but this definitely solves my use case — thanks.